Why am i getting these errors in my flutter app while building/running it?
Launching lib\main.dart on motorola one fusion in debug mode...
/C:/Users/Speed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:102:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
.push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Speed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:125:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.

'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
return result;
^
/C:/Users/Speed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:28:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
.push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Speed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:50:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
return result;
^
/C:/Users/Speed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:4:1: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
import '../modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Speed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/assorted_layout_widgets-6.1.1/lib/src/text_one_line_ellipsis_with_fade.dart:20:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'TextOneLineEllipsisWithFade' is missing implementations for these members:
Text.selectionColor
Try to either
provide an implementation,
inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
mark the class as abstract, or
provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class TextOneLineEllipsisWithFade extends StatelessWidget implements Text {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter2/flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart:592:16: Context: 'Text.selectionColor' is defined here.
final Color? selectionColor;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Speed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/assorted_layout_widgets-6.1.1/lib/src/text_one_line_ellipsis_with_fade.dart:201:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'RenderParagraphX' is missing implementations for these members:

RenderParagraph.registrar
RenderParagraph.registrar=
RenderParagraph.selectionColor
RenderParagraph.selectionColor=
RenderParagraph.selections
Try to either
provide an implementation,
inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
mark the class as abstract, or
provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class RenderParagraphX extends RenderBox
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter2/flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:194:27: Context: 'RenderParagraph.registrar' is defined here.
SelectionRegistrar? get registrar => _registrar;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter2/flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:196:7: Context: 'RenderParagraph.registrar=' is defined here.
set registrar(SelectionRegistrar? value) {
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter2/flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:428:14: Context: 'RenderParagraph.selectionColor' is defined here.
Color? get selectionColor => _selectionColor;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter2/flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:430:7: Context: 'RenderParagraph.selectionColor=' is defined here.
set selectionColor(Color? value) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter2/flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:168:27: Context: 'RenderParagraph.selections' is defined here.
List get selections {
^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\flutter2\flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1157

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.



Process 'command 'C:\flutter2\flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug
I tried to fix but i can't please help

Have you tried running with the  --scan flag for more info?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have a package name "bottom_sheet_route". This has a class name "ModalBottomSheetRoute". This class name is also available in the default flutter core.
I have checked the package and it has already been updated to resolve this conflict.
Update your "bottom_sheet_route" in pubspec.yaml to the version 3.0.0
Or
You can name the import specifically.
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart' as sheet;

Then use the class in the package like this;
sheet.ModalBottomSheetRoute(...);


my sdk version is sdk: ">=2.17.3 <3.0.0"

This is not the sdk version. It is the package "bottom_sheet_route" version. You will find it is pubspec.yaml.

can i contact you somehow
